# bsDatepicker withtimepicker, is there a way to remove AM/PM?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

im using [datepicker withtimepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=overview#with-timepicker) from ngx-bootstrap and im trying to remove the AM/PM button and force the datepicker to be in 24hours mode, is there a way to do that ?

```
                    <bs-datepicker-inline
                        [bsConfig]="{withTimepicker: true, dateInputFormat: 'MMMM DD YYYY, HH:mm'}"
                        [(bsValue)]="dateTimePickerValue"
                        (bsValueChange)="setDates($event)">
                    </bs-datepicker-inline>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Date formats are provided by moment.js.

One sample for 24h format could be: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'

You can easily change the date format by specifying the dateInputFormat in bsConfig:

```js
 [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }"
```